# prove a function is $L^{1}$

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, notation, definition, bochner-spaces

If we have a function $F:[0,T] \to H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)\times L^{2}(\Omega)$, how exactly would we show that $F\in L^{1}([0,T],H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)\times L^{2}(\Omega))$?  Is it enough to prove that $\int_{0}^{T}|F(t)|dt<\infty$?

I have seen this notation in several books, but I do not know what to make of it.

Comment: what is the definition of $L^1([0,T],H_0^1\times L^2)$ that you are using?

Comment: this is my question, i need to prove this but i don't know the definition of this space

Comment: I guess $\Omega \equiv [0,T]$ in that case or the question doesn't make sense ?

Comment: No,$\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $ R^{n}$, this notation is used in several books as a condition in theorems but there is no clear definition for it.  Maybe it can be defined as follows:$ \int_{0}^{T}$ $||F||_{H^{1}_{0}(\Omega) \times  L^{2}(\Omega)}$< $\infty$ I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look for *Bochner-Lebesgue-spaces*. You need to show that
$$
F : [0,T] \to H_0^1(\Omega) \times L^2(\Omega)
$$
is Bochner-measurable (i.e. the limit of simple measurable functions)
and
$$
\int_0^T \|F(t)\|_{H_0^1(\Omega) \times L^2(\Omega)} \, \mathrm{d}t < \infty.$$